# Cron job scheduling is not working in ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, cron, job-scheduling

1) i have a script **sp19.sh** in the path **/home/killer/Desktop/alok/scripts/test1**

```
#script to copy file 1 in test dir
a=`ls -t|cut -c 1,4|head -1`
b=`expr $a + 1`
cp "$a"  "$b"
```

2) i scheduled a task to copy a file named **1** in the same location using the below code in crontab.But this is not working.

```
m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /home/killer/Desktop/alok/scripts/test1/sp19.sh
```

3) I have already tested that the sp19.sh is correct and generating the files but cron job is not working.

Thanks

Comment: When you want to execute the script? Use the Cron maker web site to generate yours

Comment: i want it in every 1 minute

Comment: How does your script know which directory  the files it should copy reside in ?

Comment: You are right  bro, path was not given. And every time variable a was getting wrong data because of the wrong logic

Answer (score 0):

Change your Cron expression to

```
0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *
```

This will make it run every one minute.

If it doesn't work, you could take a look here

https://askubuntu.com/q/2368

Comment: no bro its not working.But i have tried to append a file using 5 * ,that is working.But copying is not working

Comment: * * * * * also makes it run every minute

Comment: Alok, add the following command on top of your script file: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: No. Actually i got the issue, the issue was with the script file.

Answer (score 0):

**The issue was with the script file**
**The correct script should be**

```
#cript to copy file 1 in test dir
a=`ls /home/killer/Desktop/alok/scripts/test1 -t|cut -c 1,4|head -1`
b=`expr $a + 1`
cp "/home/killer/Desktop/alok/scripts/test1/$a" "/home/killer/Desktop/alok/scripts/test1/$b"
```